# Special Kähler manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, connections, kahler-manifolds

These are facts from article by V. Cortes, "Realization of special Kähler manifolds as parabolic spheres". So, I tried to understand them by using the simplest example where $m = 2$ but unsuccessfully.

1. Let us have complex vector space $V=T^{*}C^{m}$ with standard complex symplectic form $\Omega =\sum_{i=1}^{m}dz^{i}\wedge dw^{i}$, and $\tau : V\to V$ is standard real structure of $V$ with set of fixed points $V^{\tau }=T^{*}R^{m}$.
2. Then $\gamma := \sqrt{-1}  \Omega (.,\tau .)$ defines a Hermitian form. A holomorphic immersion $\phi : M\to V$ of a complex manifold $M$ into $V$ is called non-degenerate if $\phi ^{*}\gamma$ is non-degenerate.
3. If $\phi$ is non-degenerate then $\phi^{*}\gamma$ defines a Kähler metric $g$ on $M$. If, additionally, $\phi$ is a Lagrangian immersion then it induces a torsion-free flat connection $\nabla$ on $M$.

How do we get metric $g$ and connection $\nabla$ on $M$?

What does it mean that $\phi^{*}\gamma$ is non-degenerate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions are answered in section 1.3 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910091). The basic ideas are as follows.

The form $\phi^\ast \gamma$ is just the pullback of $\gamma$ by $\phi$: For any $m \in M$ and vectors $u, v \in T_m M$,
$$(\phi^\ast \gamma)_m(u, v) = \gamma(d\phi_m(u), d\phi_m(v)).$$
So nondegeneracy of $\phi^\ast \gamma$ means nondegeneracy as a form, *i.e.*
$$(\phi^\ast \gamma)(u, v) = 0 \text{ for all $v$ if and only if $u = 0$}.$$

The induced metric $g$ on $M$ is $g = \mathrm{Re}(\phi^\ast \gamma)$.

Section 1.3 of the linked paper explains how to get a flat, torsion-free connection $\nabla$ on $M$ in the case that $\phi$ is a totally complex holomorphic immersion. Proposition 6 tells us that a holomorphic immersion is Lagrangian and nondegenerate if and only if it is Lagrangian and totally complex. Hence we can apply the totally complex case here to get our flat, torsion-free connection.

Comment: Is there an example of such an immersion, that is Lagrangian and totally complex? Is Kaehler immersion same as totally complex? In the paper above everything is pure theory with no examples.